# Child-element in inline-block div changes the parents siblings position

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of divs with some content (another div inside). I want the parent divs to be positioned in a nice line and I want the child div to be relative to its parent.

I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tra1wd18/1/) To illustrate. Right now the divs are all nicely placed, but if you remove the '.btn' div in the last one, everything gets messed up.

To see what I mean, change the HTML in the JSFiddle to:

```
<div id="expand1" class="expand">
  <div id="btn1" class="btn">>></div>
</div>
<div id="expand2" class="expand">
  <div id="btn2" class="btn">>></div>
</div>
<div id="expand3" class="expand"></div>
```

What's going on here? How can I get the desired result?

Comment: In which browser you are having this issue?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Chrome. Haven't tried any other

Comment: I didn't see anything strange after replacing HTML. May be you are missing something to add?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman https://jsfiddle.net/tra1wd18/7/ This gives me the undesired result

Comment: @MuhammadUsman you might have to expand the window to get the effect I'm talking about =)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Make sure that the elements are in line next to each other, not below each other.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman didn't change anything

Comment: @Johan Add `.expand{vertial-align: top;}` and your issue will be fixed.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson I always use `vertical-align` property whenever I use `inline-block` to avoid such issues.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tra1wd18/9/, cus you forgot to add float to your parent elements. For a better layout, you must use floats :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi That works great! If you make it into an answer I'll mark as correct =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use floats for a better layout:

```css
.expand{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.btn{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  top:150px;
  left: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand1" class="expand">
  <div id="btn1" class="btn">>></div>
</div>
<div id="expand2" class="expand">
  <div id="btn2" class="btn">>></div>
</div>
<div id="expand3" class="expand"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.expand {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.btn{
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand1" class="expand">
  <div id="btn1" class="btn">>></div>
</div>
<div id="expand2" class="expand">
  <div id="btn2" class="btn">>></div>
</div>
<div id="expand3" class="expand"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply play with the position property to get the desired result.

just add *position:relative* to your .**expand** class

```
.expand {
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

and update the position to *absolute* to your .**btn** class

```
.btn {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
```